# Load Images On Click - Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Loading sets of images on button click instead of all. I know there are plugins for lazy load, but just wanted to try this.

**Logic :** Already have the data ( say 30 images ) in an array '`Images`'. Bound a temp array '`temp`' to the li and pushing set of 4 images from 'Images' to 'temp' on button click.

When I click the button, the images just flash and vanish. Where am i going wrong.

```
<div ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="image in temp">
      <img ng-src="{{image.src}}" />
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="loadMore()">LOAD MORE</button>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var DemoApp = angular.module("DemoApp", []);
        DemoApp.controller("DemoController",
              function DemoController($scope) {
                  $scope.quantity = 0;
                  $scope.temp = [];
                  $scope.loadMore = function () {
                      for (i = $scope.quantity; i <= $scope.quantity + 1; i++)
                      {
                          $scope.temp.push($scope.images[i]);
                      }
                      $scope.quantity = i;
                  }

                  $scope.images = [
                      { "src": "Images/1.jpg" },
                      { "src": "Images/2.jpg" },
                      { "src": "Images/3.jpg" },
                      ......
                      { "src": "Images/4.jpg" }
                  ];
              });
    </script>
```

It's working in fiddle but not in my page.

http://jsfiddle.net/6cZ48/

Comment: Fiddle has, 'No wrap - in <body>. Do I have to do something for that in code. Cause it's still flashing the images. They wont stay on page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its working Fine

Take a look at this

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V5vZ4/)**

```
 var DemoApp = angular.module("DemoApp", []);
 DemoApp.controller("DemoController",

 function DemoController($scope) {
     $scope.quantity = 0;
     $scope.temp = [];
     $scope.loadMore = function () {
         for (i = $scope.quantity; i <= $scope.quantity + 3; i++) {
             $scope.temp.push($scope.images[i]);
         }
         $scope.quantity = i + 1;
     }

     $scope.images = [{
         "src": "http://www.db4free.net/images/db4free-logo.png"
     }, {
         "src": "http://static.jsbin.com/images/github-32.png"
     }, {
         "src": "http://www.db4free.net/images/db4free-logo.png"
     }, {
         "src": "http://static.jsbin.com/images/github-32.png"
     }];
 });
```

Comment: Fiddle has, 'No wrap - in <body>. Do I have to do something for that in code. Cause it's still flashing the images. They wont stay on page.

Comment: Unable to see preview. I updated my fiddle in the question. It's working fine. It's the same in the developed page. The images just flash and vanish. What could be the reason.

Comment: I changed it to `<input type="button"/>` and it works now. Thanks again.